# NPM Err: Unable to resolve dependencies

Tags: npm, langchain, npx, pinecone, langchain-js

I am building this web app that will allow a user to chat with their pdf. I am using pinecone as the vector database and also using langchain. So I npm installed pinecone before langchain but when it came to installing langchain I got an error about peer dependency issues between the two packages.

The error indicates that there is a conflict between the required version of @pinecone-database/pinecone in the @langchain/community package ("^1.1.0") and the version found in the root project ("^2.0.1").
Typically this error has been consistently present at the very last minute whenever I tried installing any dependency from that point on and results in failure to properly install them.

here:

npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @langchain/community@0.0.19
npm ERR! Found: @pinecone-database/pinecone@2.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@pinecone-database/pinecone
npm ERR!   @pinecone-database/pinecone@"^2.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peerOptional @pinecone-database/pinecone@"^1.1.0" from @langchain/community@0.0.19
npm ERR! node_modules/@langchain/community
npm ERR!   @langchain/community@"~0.0.17" from langchain@0.1.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/langchain
npm ERR!     langchain@"^0.1.4" from the root project
npm ERR!   @langchain/community@"^0.0.19" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @pinecone-database/pinecone@1.1.3
npm ERR! node_modules/@pinecone-database/pinecone
npm ERR!   peerOptional @pinecone-database/pinecone@"^1.1.0" from @langchain/community@0.0.19
npm ERR!   node_modules/@langchain/community
npm ERR!     @langchain/community@"~0.0.17" from langchain@0.1.4
npm ERR!     node_modules/langchain
npm ERR!       langchain@"^0.1.4" from the root project
npm ERR!     @langchain/community@"^0.0.19" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-01-22T07_42_33_360Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2024-01-22T07_42_33_360Z-debug-0.log

To solve this issue, I previously flagged them using --legacy-peer-deps flag and that allowed me to install any package along the way.

I also attempted to update the packages using the command 'npm update'

However, whenever I needed to run a command that starts with npx, like for example npx shadcn-ui@latest add tooltip, the component won't be installed because npx doesn't recognize the --legacy-peer-deps flag and neither the --force flag as well.

I have tried looking for solutions everywhere including the langchain documentation but none has helped solve this issue so far.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue, and here's how I solved it:

Downgrading the version of pinecone doesn't help - it will most likely "break" it, and you will get a `PineconeConnectionError`. Using `--force` or `--legacy-peer-deps` are not sustainable options as you will need to use npx.

Langchain is still a young project and changes quite rapidly. In their documentation, they clearly explain that Langchain should be installed using `npm install -S langchain` and that `@langchain/community` is now automatically included as part of the initial langchain install, in `langchain/core`. If you get both `langchain` AND `@langchain/community`, this will trigger the dependency conflict.

TO FIX:

1. **Remove all references to `langchain/community` using `npm uninstall` + delete occurences of this package in `package.json` - only keep the `langchain` package**.
2. **Delete your `node_modules`, `package-lock.json`and `npm cache clean`**
3. **Run `npm install`**

Your app will be running fine after, without having to `--force` or `--legacy-peer-deps` all your commands. If you read the documentation, you would see that all your Langchain imports can be made from the `langchain` package.

Comment: Thanks for your in-depth solution. I'll surely try this. I had put that project in the back burner for awhile. However, the reason I actually had langchain/community was because of the MDN which kept recommending to use it instead of just langchain. Or maybe because I didn't use the "npm install -S langchain". I had assumed the -S while installing.